# Configuring a systemd service to start when another is reloaded

Tags: systemd

With the WantedBy= install directive and Before= unit directive in the unit config for a oneshot service B, I can start B when another service A is (re)started. However, I'm not sure how to configure B.service such that it also starts before A is reloaded.

I've looked at the ReloadPropagatedFrom= directive, but it implies that a reload of A.service will trigger a reload of B.service, not a start of B.service.

Comment: Have you actually tried `ReloadPropagatedFrom` or just read the documentation.

Comment: I did try it and it didn't seem to have any effect on the dependent service, i.e. reloading A didn't seem to do anything to B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no "good" solution within SystemD then you can make the reload part of the unit file. Just prepend the existing `ExecReload` entry with another one:

```
ExecReload=systemctl restart B
```

Comment: Alright, thanks.

For those needing to do this in an override, clear ExecReload first.

    [Service]
    ExecReload=
    ExecReload=systemctl restart B
    ExecReload=<original ExecReload>